# Android Studio dependency search not include latest version

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play-services

I've created an Android project to use 'play-services'. When I search the library in project structure dependencies tab, it finds some old version. But after importing this version of the library, AS hints me for a newer version which cannot be synchronized with Gradle build process. How can I use latest versions?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Try : https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup

Comment: Since version 11.2.0 of Play Services, artifacts have been released on the Google maven server. Have you updated your repositories list in your build scripts to include the Google maven server?

Comment: @clownba0t yes I included 'google()' in my root build.gradle.

Comment: Have you added google() or maven dependency in your your top-level build.gradle?

Comment: Which version of the Android gradle plugin are you using?

Comment: 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'

Comment: com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1